# KineticJS stage.toDataURL() works with mimeType png but not jpeg

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, kineticjs

I have a pretty simple app that I'm writing to customize the colors on a hockey glove and export it to JPEG. However the jpeg file format doesn't seem to be working, it only displays the bottom-left image for some strange reason. Here is the url:

http://jtdsdev.com/glove_customizer/canvas-test2.html

Here is some sample code:
JS

```
function draw(){
.... 
code to draw paths 
....
document.getElementById("preview").addEventListener("click", function() {
      stage.toDataURL({
        mimeType: "image/jpeg",
        quality: 1,
        callback: function(dataUrl) {
              document.getElementById("img_preview").src = dataUrl;
        }
      });
    }, false);
}
```

HTML

```
<body style="background-color:white">
    <div id="container">
    <button id="preview" name="preview" >Preview</button>
    <br>
    <img id="img_preview">
    </div>
....
</body>
```

The full code can be seen at the link above.

Answer (score 0):

It should work this way:

```
     stage.toDataURL({
        mimeType: "image/jpeg",
        quality: 1.0,
        callback: function(dataUrl) {
             ...
        }
      });
```